# Create dynamic html file from code behind and open in a new window

Tags: html, vb.net, popup

I'm letting my users write their own HTML from my webpage.

When they click the preview button, my code behind needs access to controls on the page (and so I understand I can't use a web method here).

It builds the HTML and saves it as a file on the server.

My question is: 
Once the file has been made, I want to automatically open the file in a new window for the user to see their handy work.

I'm using vb.net, but happy to receive c# answers.

Thanks folks !
.
.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=--=-=-
Thank you very much Jan !!

I still have a slight problem though...
My code goes like this:

```
If fileExists Then
        Do Until fileExists = False
            tmpFormPreviewFileName = "Test" & GetRandomNumber() & ".html"
            tmpFormPreviewFilePath = Server.MapPath("~") & "Pages\FormPreviews\" & tmpFormPreviewFileName
            fileExists = My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(tmpFormPreviewFileName)
        Loop
    End If

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(tmpFormPreviewFilePath, strHTML, False)


    'Now open the file in a new window
    btnPreview.OnClientClick = String.Format("window.open('/Pages/FormPreviews/{0}', 'myPopup', 'width=400,height=500')", tmpFormPreviewFileName)
```

So, the problem is - I don't know what the filename will be until after the user has clicked the preview button and the `OnClientClick` event won't fire until the user clicks the button for the 2nd time (which of course creates another HTML file)

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
I'm still having problems getting the popup to work.
Here's my code at the moment:

```
'create a JavaScript command for opening the file in popup window
    Dim strScript As String = String.Format("window.open('/Pages/FormPreviews/{0}, 'myPopup', 'width=400,height=500')", tmpFormPreviewFileName)

    'register the JavaScript to be executed when web page loads
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "openPopup", strScript, True)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "ShowMsg", "javascript:alert('Test Msg');", True)
```

My "ShowMsg" fires succesfully, but the line above it (the popup code) doesn't seem to work. Can you see what's going wrong at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your missing a quote in your JavaScript (see below)

```
Dim strScript As String = String.Format("window.open('/Pages/FormPreviews/{0}<-- here
```

Try this:

```
Dim strScript As String = String.Format("window.open('/Pages/FormPreviews/{0}', 'myPopup', 'width=400,height=500')", tmpFormPreviewFileName)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !... 
it always seems to be those tiny little sneaky bits that take a long time to notice :)

Answer (score 1):

1) First you have to make the saved HTML files accessible through the web.
The simplest way is to save them to some subfolder of your website - e.g. let's create a "/GeneratedPages" folder.

When saving a file to this folder, you will need to construct a physical path to this folder. You  can use the [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method for it.

You will probably also have to set access rights to allow web application wrtting data to the folder.

2) Now let's implement opening of the preview window:

Assuming your Preview button is declared in your ASXP page as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPreview" runat="server" Text="Preview" />
```

Then you have just to add the following statement to code-behind, e.g. to the Page_Load method:

```
// sample name of one generate file
string pageName = "page1.html";     
btnPreview.OnClientClick = string.Format("window.open('/GeneratedPages/{0}', 'myPopup', 'width=400,height=500')", pageName);
```

More information about the used *window.open* method can be found in Javascript reference, e.g. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

UPDATE:
If are constructing the file just after clicking on the button (in a postback), then you can use a [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) method. Your server-side click handler for the preview button can be following:

```
protected void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tmpFormPreviewFileName;

    // construct the filename and save the file
    // ...

    // create a JavaScript command for opening the file in popup window
    string script = string.Format("window.open('/Pages/FormPreviews/{0}, 'myPopup', 'width=400,height=500')", tmpFormPreviewFileName);

    // registger the JavaScript to be executed when web page loads
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "openPupup", script, true);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan - thank you very much for helping !
I've update my original question to illustrate my new problem...

Comment: Hi wotney, I've updated my answer according to your question update.

Comment: Hi again Jan,I really appreciate you helping me out with this one - thank you very much !
I still have a problem though.  I'll update my original question...

Comment: Once again - Thank you very much for helping me get that sorted. Very much appreciated Jan !